# How to upgrade a React project built with create-react-app to the next create-react-app version?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a React project built with `create-react-app` 1.5. I would like to get the features of `create-react-app` 2.0 for my React project.

Specifically I would like to use this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/3909

Comment: This post need an updated answer due to CRA no longer being maintained. Is there a way to update deep dependencies of CRA / react-script?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Basically, to upgrade a `create-react-app` project, [all you need to do is update the `react-scripts` module to the latest version](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#updating-to-new-releases) and update your app to be compatible with any breaking changes in `react-scripts`.

Run [`yarn upgrade --latest react-scripts`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/#toc-yarn-upgrade-package-latest-l-caret-tilde-exact-pattern), rebuild your app, and everything should more-or-less work, barring any breaking changes.

Comment: For anyone out here searching for `npm` command: `npm i -s --save-exact react-scripts@desired_version` where `desired_version` is a version you want to update to.

Comment: Is there a way to update the `react-scripts` package without upgrading `create-react-app`? Would `npm update` work?

Comment: Sometimes it worth nuking your node_modules folder and start fresh to please webpack.

Comment: After updating the script from 2.0 to 3.0 by using above command, if the css not loading then change name of css from style.css to style.module.css. I know this is not part of this question but I shared this info may be helpful to someone.

Comment: `npm install react-scripts@latest` is the recommanded way to upgrade react-scripts, as seen on [their homepage](https://create-react-app.dev/).