# How to fix breaking change on homepage after update react-scripts (create react app)

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, package.json

According to [How to upgrade a React project built with create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48727922/10477687), I have updated react-scripts from v1.1.4 to v3.4.3. However, there's a question on homepage that I cannot solve properly.

In previous package.json, I have `"homepage": "/temp_project/resources"`
After I've updated react-scripts to v3.4.3, everything works fine except
when **npm start** (`"start": "react-scripts start"`), path will becomes http://localhost:3000/temp_project/resources
which is not expected. (Expected to have http://localhost:3000/ )
Hot fix = manually change the path to http://localhost:3000/ everytime

If I change `"homepage": "/temp_project/resources"` to `"homepage": "/"`, then my http://localhost:8080/temp_project (index page) becomes a blank page. And my **npm start** (`"start": "react-scripts start"`) work fine.

What should I do?? Sorry if it's a fool question. Thank you.

Supplement:

it's a maven spring boot project using [eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin)
and [maven-resources-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-resources-plugin/3.0.2)

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "homepage": "/temp_project/resources",
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `"homepage": "."` or maybe `"homepage": "./"` for that matter... let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've tried both of them and both of them work perfectly in npm start (3000) , but 8080 index page is still blank which's not accepted.

Comment: Can you post `package.json` and the project folder structure?

Comment: added supplement in the question

Comment: Problem finally solved after I updated to "homepage": "../resources". Your answer should be correct. Thanks so much.